# Unable to establish SSL connection DNS 320

Tags: server, openssl, wget

I am trying to install a webserver using wget on a DNS 320 NAS but I keep having this problem
"OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection."
[image]

I kind of understood that I have either have wbget or OpenSSL outdated but I don't know how to update them since i cannot use wget and I don't have the perms with filezilla to upload directly inside the directory "Z:\ffp\funpkg\installed"
[image]

## wget version --2022-10-31 23:21:59--

## openssl versionOpenSSL 0.9.7d 17 Mar 2004

[image]

I tryed installing using ssl commands with wget --no-check-certificate http://openssl.org/source/
Sliding the dir via filezilla and using the Z:dir in my file explorer

none worked

Comment: Yes OpenSSL 0.9.7 is WAY obsolete; the newest protocol it supports is TLS1.0 which was mostly broken in 2011 and has been generally prohibited and unsupported since about 2014-2015. This is not a problem with the certificate and options to ignore certificate problems are completely irrelevant and useless. If filezilla and file explorer can't write to the desired directory, use one of them to write to some other directory where you do have access, then login to the NAS and move or copy it from that directory to the desired directory.

Comment: Yes! I didn't think of using the nas directly, i thought that filezilla had all the admin perms.

All the files for the pakages are in arm-4 but i cannot find this format for my openssl file, I only come across .tas.gz files, is this also because of obsolete component or did I just not find the right file